# 5 BUTTONS for one action

Tags: if-statement, boolean

I required some assistance on the code, I manage to to create this the code for 5 button and one action, however i run on the phone it does when I clicked on the button.
Can some advise me why?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.example.android.testing1.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="104dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Button1"

            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="100dp"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Button3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
            android:text="Button4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Button5" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    package com.example.android.testing1;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import static android.R.id.button1;
    import static android.R.id.button2;
    import static android.R.id.button3;
    import static com.example.android.testing1.R.id.button4;
    import static com.example.android.testing1.R.id.button5;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button dodo = (Button) findViewById(button1);

            Button dede = (Button) findViewById(button2);

            Button dada = (Button) findViewById(button3);

            Button didi = (Button) findViewById(button4);

            Button hehe = (Button) findViewById(button5);

            return;

        }

        //boolean fafa, soso, raerae, gaga, gege;
        public void main(Button args[]) {
            final boolean fafa = true;
            final boolean soso = true;
            final boolean raerae = true;
            final boolean gaga = true;
            final boolean gege = true;
            boolean returrn;


            OnClickListener list = new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (fafa == true && soso == true && raerae == true && gaga == true && gege == true) {
                        Toast GetMeToast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Open all buttons", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        GetMeToast.show();

                    }
                }


            };


        }}
```

I tried to run the code above but was jammed once i clicked the button.

I am new to java. Required some assistance, what i need is that by clicking all the 5 buttons then the toast will appear.

I have tried many way it does not work. I think by creating a Boolean and if method can help me with this.

Comment: Rather than using buttons here, something like checkboxes might work better.

Comment: The task require me to use button.